# Session variable in C# desktop application?

Tags: c#

I am developing a C# a stand alone single user desktop application that requires the user to login to the application. I want to ensure that when there is no activity for 5 minutes or so the application will prompt the user to login again. I have several solution in mind to do this but there do not seem efficient. Previously while doing web programming i was able to do this kind of feature using session variable are there are similiar kind of features in C# that can be used for desktop application.

Comment: you can use a simple timer for that

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Auto-Logout Within a Windows Forms Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603374/how-to-auto-logout-within-a-windows-forms-application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to set a 5-minute timer that is always running, and logs the user out when it ticks. Then you can have any activity restart the timer from the beginning.

If this is a WinForms app, you can have your top-level forms implement `IMessageFilter`. In your `PreFilterMessage` function you would restart the timer and return `false` for messages that indicate activity (`WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, etc.) to let everything get processed normally.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had a similiar solution in mind too. I will implement this.

Answer (score 2):

You can always add a trigger to auto-logout within a Windows Forms Application. Here is a link with examples with an accepted answer

[How can I trigger an auto-logout within a Windows Forms Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603374/how-to-auto-logout-within-a-windows-forms-application)

> To monitor user activity, you could create a custom Form-based class
>   from which your application forms will inherit. There you can
>   subscribe to the MouseMove and KeyDown events (setting the KeyPreview
>   property to true), either of which will be raised whenever the user is
>   active. You can then create a System.Threading.Timer, with the due
>   time set to 30 minutes, and postpone it using the Change() method
>   whenever user activity is detected.

Answer (score 0):

No, but session state is just a list of variables to help overcome the stateless nature of web applications.  Since desktop applications are not stateless, there's no need.  I'd just use a simple timer or something similar and log the user out after 5 minutes of inactivity.